# Facebook Chat Client on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, 14.04, facebook, client

I'd like to install & configure a **Facebook Chat** client on **Ubuntu 14.04 14.04 Trusty Tahr** to increase my collaboration & work flow with other Students in a Group Chat.

If at all possible I would enjoy the ability to run the client from terminal (in my case, terminator).

My intitial investigation pathway is below.

---

Previous question: [Is there a Facebook messenger app](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276550/is-there-an-facebook-messenger-app)

Answer leads me to 
[here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/fbmessenger-stand-alone-facebook.html)
But at the address it says:

> "Application will stop working on March 3, 2014. No lead."

**Reference 2:**
[Integrate Facebook messenger (not chat or facebook)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266042/integrate-facebook-messenger-not-chat-or-facebook)
The answer to this question is using the GUI alternative "empathy" which is OK.
But is it possible to run empathy without a GUI from terminal?

---

Still looking for possible solutions.

Regards,

Comment: http://fbcmd.dtompkins.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Facebook messenger app](http://askubuntu.com/questions/276550/is-there-a-facebook-messenger-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at this [Facebook Terminal Script](https://github.com/kissrobber/facebook_client_terminal)

To test it out, there is a [demo here](http://kissrobber.github.io/facebook_client_terminal/)

You can get your messages with:

```
api me/inbox
```

I don't know if there is a method to send a message.

Comment: worked great ;) cheers, it's a shame XMPP doesn't support group chat though.